# Share and update code Android

Tags: android, project, share

I want to start writing a project in android with my friend. I would like to share my code with him all the time and conversely. 
May I say what I mean for example, I start writing new thing (for example new activity or class) and it is sent to database or something when i'm connected to the internet, now when he open project and have connection our code is updated about this new thing.

(sorry for english)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

Comment: Buy an USB stick then when your code is complete put it on the USB stick and send the stick to your friend by DHL

Answer (score 0):

Shared source control - Try GitHub

https://github.com/

It you want to collaborate in real time something like TeamViewer

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx